# Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'values' and TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to do the followings:

Step 1) Let Player1 select from 'X' or 'O'.
Step 2) Once they have made a choice between "X" or "O", then they have to select numbers of their choice.
Step 3) A dictionary is created that stores "X" or "O" with respect to the number in step 2.
Step 4) Print the values of that dictionary in the form of a list.

When I try to use `g.values()` I get an error:

> Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Earlier with the same code, it was making a dictionary g but I have started to get an error:

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Here is my code:

```
Player_1_Selection = input("Player_1 choose your marker from 'X' or 'O'")
Player_1_Selection = Player_1_Selection.upper()
if Player_1_Selection == "X":
   Player_2_Selection = "O"
else:
   Player_2_Selection = "X"
print (Player_1_Selection, Player_2_Selection)
g = {}
for i in range (0,5):
    for i in range(0,1):
        Selection_i = input ("Player 1 Select your place: ")
        a = (Selection_i)
        g[a] = Player_1_Selection
    for i in range(0,1):
        Selection_i = input ("Player 2 Select your place: ")
        g = (Selection_i)
        g[a] = Player_2_Selection
g = sorted (g)
print(g)
print (g.values())`
```

Answer (score 0):

`g = sorted(g)` will make a **list** out of the *keys* of the dict `g`.

I haven't really understood your game's rules, though, so I'm not sure what it is you really want. Maybe `g = sorted(g.values())`?

Comment: its in the initial stage only. I just want to capture the responses of two players one after the other for five turns, therefore, the for loop runs for 5 iterations. g.value() is not working and giving me a result that "Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'". I tried to run the code after some time and now it says  " TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment" in the code line where I assign a = Selection_i . I am just trying to make a dictionary that holds value for player selections.{ '1': X, '2':O, '3':X, '4':O, '5':X, '6':X, '7':O, '8':X, '9':O, '10':X}